# jQuery update value with its parent in format

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have html markup like this

```
<input type="hidden" value="" id="shortcode_selected_package" name="shortcode_selected_package">
<div class="selected-packages-wrap">
    <div class="shortcode-wrap">
        <a class="data-remove" href="#" data-id="417" data-name="Test New Packs">-</a><label>Test New Packs</label>
        <span class="checkbox-wrap">
            <span><input type="checkbox" value="5">10 GB</span>
            <span><input type="checkbox" value="26">Sony</span>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div class="shortcode-wrap">
        <a class="data-remove" href="#" data-id="220" data-name="New custom pack">-</a><label>New custom pack</label>
        <span class="checkbox-wrap">
            <span><input type="checkbox" value="5">10 GB</span>
            <span><input type="checkbox" value="25">Unlimited Calls</span>
        </span>
    </div>

    </div>
```

Here you can see in the first div element there are two checkbox with value 5, 26 (10 GB and Sony). So when someone check the checkbox of first div ten its value should be added with its parent value in the shortcode_selected_package div.

So lets say when user check both 10 GB and Sony then the value of the div should be like this

```
417[5|26]
```

if user checks the checkbox for the 2nd div then the value should be like this

```
417[5|26],220[5,25]
```

But if user unchecks any checkbox then its value should be remove from the set value. Like if user unchecks Unlimited Calls from the 2nd div then the value should be like

```
417[5|26],220[5,25]
```

I have tried this code but the values are not updating

```
$('body').on('click', '.selected-packages-wrap input[type=checkbox]', function() {
    var PackageSelected = $('input#shortcode_selected_package').val();
    var selectedVal = this.value;
    var ParentId = $(this).parents('.shortcode-wrap').find('a.data-remove').attr('data-id');

    if( this.checked ) {
      selectPackage(ParentId, selectedVal, PackageSelected);
    }
    else {
      unselectPackage(ParentId, selectedVal, PackageSelected);
    }
  });

  function selectPackage(ParentId, selectedVal, PackageSelected) {
    Packages = PackageSelected.split(',');
    var Arr = [];
    if(jQuery.inArray(ParentId, Packages) !== -1) {
      $.each( Packages, function( key, val ) {
        if( val == ParentId ) {
          Packages[key] = val.replace(val, val + '[' + selectedVal + ']');
          Arr.push(Packages);
        }
      });

      console.log(Arr[0]);
    }

  }
```

Comment: what is the #shortcode_selected_package value when init? then where u fill?

Comment: if value like "417[5|26]", .split(',') & jQuery.inArray is not work.

Comment: @Vin its the value which will be stored into the database which has been selected. So if once it has been set I will store into the database and again fetch it.

Comment: Why used two differents separators : `417[5|26]` `220[5,25]` ? Or maybe it's a mistake then : `220[5|25]` ?

Answer (score 0):

First, I think that you should put the data-id of the link as a checkbox attribute or better yet at each div holding the checkboxes (it will be more convienient for selection instead of doing:

```
.parents('.shortcode-wrap').find('a.data-remove').attr('data-id');
```

)

Then what you do is every time on change or on click of any of the checkboxes you loop through the divs with class of shortcode wrap.

```
$('.selected-packages-wrap input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
  var checkboxes_data = [];
  // Loop through the divs
  for(var divs_count = 0; divs_count < $('.shortcode-wrap').length; divs_count++) {
    checkboxes_data[divs_count] = {div_id: $('.shortcode-wrap:eq(' + divs_count + ')').attr('data-id'), checkboxes_id: [],}
    // Loop through the checkboxes
    for(var chBox_count = 0; chBox < $('.shortcode-wrap:eq(' + divs_count + ') input[type=checkbox]').length; chBox_count++) {
      var $.current_checkbox = $('.shortcode-wrap:eq(' + divs_count + ') input[type=checkbox]:eq(' + chBox_count + ')');
      // If the checkbox is checked add the value to the array
      if($.current_checkbox.is(":checked")) {
        checkboxes_data[divs_count].checkboxes_id.push($.current_checkbox.val()
      }
    }
  }

  var final_value = '';
  // Goes trough the the newly created array adds the div value followed by the corresponding checkboxes value
  checkboxes_data.forEach(function(div) {
    var checkbox_ids = div.checkbox_ids.join(", ");
    final_value += div.div_id + '[' + div.checkbox_ids + '], ';
  });

  $('#shortcode_selected_package').val(final_value);
});
```